# Symfony - Agile Toolkit - Yii -> PHP Framework for AdminPanel/Webinterface

Tags: php, panel, web-frameworks

I would like to build a small Webinterface which should be easy to expand, so I wanna use a PHP Framework. I never realy worked with a Framework and couldn't find much in the internet.

Could you give me one to three advantages and disadvantages to these or other known PHP Frameworks which could help me decide?

some facts:

- easy start (I'm "new" to php frameworks)
- easy to expand
- good user management
- compatibility to css/javascript themes/frameworks

Answer (score 0):

Difficult to say for other frameworks, Agile Toolkit is specifically targeted at abstracting User Interface.

That means you focus on the business logic, and events and routing, but the framework offers a lot of visual objects to present your data inside grids, list, forms:

https://agiletoolkit.org/intro/1